# Django localisation path separator Windows (\) vs macOS (/)

Tags: django, windows, localization, gettext

We've been maintaining a Django website with a few Mac and Linux users (through GitHub), but now a Windows-only person joined the team.
We've come to one annoying little difference concerning the creation of `.po` localisation files.

So far, we've always had paths with forward slashes: `#: core/templates/home.html:8`, but the Windows user generates paths with backslashes: `#: .\core\templates\home.html:8`.

This makes it much more difficult to spot changes, since 750+ lines change everytime, rather than only the new or changed text & translations.

I tried myself on a Windows computer and have the same result.

What can we do to unify this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** to clarify, we're a small team without dedicated (external) translators. Whoever changes or adds stuff, generally should also add and update the localisation files.

Comment: Instead of writing the fulls paths you can use `os.path.join()` so you won't need to use (back)slashes or you can check the `pathlib` package

Comment: Is it necessary that the person on Windows generates the .po files and commits them? If you only generate them centrally, e.g. via a commit hook, or when you're ready to send the translation files to your translators, you won't have that issue.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis, the paths are generated automatically, so I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @dirkgroten, That is a possibility, but since we're a small team we don't have dedicated translators and translate everything ourselves before making a pull request (since we only have Dutch, our native language, and English as localisations)

Comment: @ThijsB. Then you could give the windows user a script that replaces all the slashes before commit

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `makemessages` command (*django.core.management.commands.makemessages*), based on the original. All you need to do is subclass `BuildFile`, overriding `postprocess_messages` to replace the slashes.

Then you subclass `Command` to use your own `BuildFile` subclass (it's just a class attribute `build_file_class`).